# Flying over the handlebars

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I am riding my bike and the front wheel suddenly stops, so I am flying over the handlebars. How can i calculate the force on my body when it throws me over the handlebars?

Comment: that's fictitious force.

Answer (score 2):

There is no physical force acting on your body.  As @FangXie pointed out, the “force” you experience is a fictitious force. It the same thing as having something on the seat of your car slide on the seat when you make a hard corner or brake hard. What you (and the thing on the seat of your car) is experiencing is a consequence of Newton’s first law, which states that an object will remain at rest or in uniform motion in a straight line unless acted upon by an external force.

You and your bike were together in motion. An external force brought your bike to an abrupt stop (in reality it will never be in zero time, but let’s say for simplicity). But since you are not “anchored” to the seat of your bike, no external force brought you to a stop (we’ll ignore the restraint of the handlebars), and therefore you will continue to move forward with the same velocity you had before impact.

Now you could, in theory, estimate the external force that would be necessary to bring you to a stop over a specified distance (assuming you let go of the handlebars).  By the work-energy principle, the change in kinetic energy equals work done, or:

$$\frac{mv^2}{2}=Fd$$

Where, $m$ is your mass, $v$ is your velocity just prior to the bike stopping, $F$ is an external force applied to you in the direction opposite your motion, and $d$ is the stopping distance.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the reference frame of the center of the wheel, you will have an acceleration magnitude forward equal to the acceleration (backwards) of the center of the wheel in the reference frame of the road. The comment about a "fictitious force" arises because of the accelerated reference frame attached to the wheel and the fact that there is no direct interaction with your body that pulls it off the bicycle.

The effective force, relative to the bicycle, would simply be the mass times the acceleration magnitude of the bicycle.  When you say suddenly, you cannot in reality say zero.  The bicycle wheel will take time to stop.

Consider a certain speed in two situations: 1) A long stopping time will mean a lower acceleration and less effective force and the person's reaction time will allow them to exert force on the handlebars to prevent flying off. 2) Shorter stopping (from the same speed as before) would mean a larger effective force, but the important item is the person's reaction time. They may not be able to react and brace.

Another consideration aside from the "force" is the torque exerted on the center of mass of the person. If the stopping time is long, the  effective torque on the body relative to the wheel axle (which shows up  in the bicycle frame due to the stopping ) will be smaller than the torque produced by gravity, so the person won't begin rotating forward over the handlebars.  If the stopping time is short, there may be more "forward" torque than there is gravitationally-provided torque, and the person won't be able to prevent forward rotation.

How to calculate a numbers for the force (not so important) or torque (more important)? It all depends on the stopping time, and that can't be zero.